# jqGrid remove ui-state-highlight on multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jQgrid with a multiselect option set to true. When the multiselect checkbox is checked, I don't want to highlight the rows in the grid.
The checkbox has an id of "#cb_emplist "

I tried the following, it works in chrome consol but not in the code

```
$("#cb_emplist").change(function() {
            $('#empList tr').removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
        });
```

---

I also tried :

```
 $("#cb_emplist").change(function () {
            if ($("#cb_emplist").is(":checked")) {
                $('#empList list tr').removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
            }          
        });
```

---

```
jQuery("#empList").jqGrid({
.....

...
multiselect: true
...
});
```

---

---

Solved with this puppy here:

```
$("#cb_emplist").on("click", function() {
            $('#empList tr').removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
        });
```

Comment: can you create a http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have done the trick:

```
 $("#cb_emplist").on("click", function() {
                $('#empList tr').removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

For the code which is dynamic you may need to delegate the events like below

```
$(document).delegate("#cb_busgrplist", "change", function({
   $('#empList tr').removeClass("ui-state-highlight"); 
});
```

Read the Delegate documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: Linking to the documentation and all, did you notice the line saying "As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method" ??

Comment: This is what I was looking for: $("#cb_emplist").on("click", function() {
                $('#empList tr').removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
            });